# jQuery scrollTo plugin problem. Nothing's moving?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm having real trouble trying to get a `div` to scroll on a page I'm building.

I basically have a `div` element, which has a much wider `div` inside that I want to scroll along to show different areas, and as such change the content. Basically a tab slider but a little different.

I've set it up currently to work on hover of the `div` in question, the event triggers but nothing happens. Please help!.

The URL is: http://ram.grtest.com/ and click 'Join'. Hover over the content in there and the event should trigger. Don't click 'Next >' - that submits a form!

Here's the initialisation (test data, i'll adjust the amount of movement later)

```
$('#join-content').hover(function(){
    $('#join-wrapper-scroll').scrollTo({axis: 'x',left:'+=100'}, 2000);
    return false;   
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does `#join-wrapper-scroll` have an inside layer before the content? I.e.

```
<div id="join-wrapper-scroll">
    <ul> <!-- inner layer -->
        <li>Content that scrolls.</li>
        <li>Content that scrolls.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You need an "inner layer" or else the plugin won't understand what it's scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use animate:

```
$("#join-wrapper-scroll").animate({"left": "-=600"}, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't really want to use animate(). Mostly because it's infinite, I suppose i'd have to go into more effort to stop it going past certain points. Giving up on scrollTo though.

Comment: I mean, if i click 'left', it goes left. and then if i do it again, it does it again, and again, and again etc.. With scrollto it can't go any further than the size of the div

Comment: You can't scroll it because it's not a scrolling div.  If you use animate, you can check that the css left property is less than the width of the div minus the width of its parent to prevent it from going too far.  Also, if you give .hover() one argument, that function will be run on both mouseenter and mouseleave.  You may want to give it two functions, one for each event, or check event.type to determine the direction to animate.